# Jbehave - Run method after a specific scenario

Tags: bdd, jbehave, gherkin

I'm trying to configure JBehave with Gherkin to run a teardown method after a **specific** scenario. So far I'm aware of the below:

- JBehave supports Gherkin, which has a syntax for Lifecycle before
  event, unfortunately Gherkin doesn't support the Lifecycle after.

  http://jbehave.org/reference/latest/story-syntax.html
- JBehave supports the annotation @AfterScenario which can only be specified to on the outcome of the scenario. This is run after **all** scenarios in a story rather after a **specific** scenario.

  http://jbehave.org/reference/latest/annotations.html

At the moment I have include a Gherkin step (@Then teardown this sceanrio) at the end my scenario within my story. This contradicts the point of BDD which should only display what the user is doing and not what the test needs to do.

Comment: have you tried to combine AfterScenario with [Context.getCurrentScenario()](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/javadoc/core/org/jbehave/core/context/Context.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't a way to access the META tags in the after scenario methods.  As a workaround that doesn't require you to duplicate your entire scenario file couldn't you leave all of the scenarios from your current class that don't require the teardown where they are, and move the one that does need the teardown into its own class which inherits from the first class.  Then, add the after scenario method to the second class.